# How programmatically show Google Maps v2 toolbar

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to display the toolbar on Google Maps v2 but it's only work when I touch on Marker.

I'm already implemented [Litle mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite#as_an_xml_attribute_for_a_mapview_or_mapfragment) and worked, but I also need user interaction (drag).

What I've tried:

- Force marker click
- Force showInfoWindow();

Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean)` to *true*?

Comment: @Koh That enables to toolbar, but does not necessarily *show* it. The toolbar is only shown when a `Marker` is selected by the user. I have not found a way to *show* the toolbar programmatically.